# Get data from a "log" table to a mySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I need to check the data in a log table to see if the user has previously read a post. My log table is named **foretag_kontaktervisadbrf2017** and it contains information about who has read a post. How can I edit my query so that i get information telling me if i have read a post or not?

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT 
    brfbolagsverket.BrfNamn
    , brfextra.BrfId
    , brfextra.Organisationsnr
    , brfextra.Gatuadress
    , brfextra.Ort
    , brfextra.Lagenheter
    , brfextra.ByggAr
    , BrfHarFastighet.Fangdatum    
FROM 
    (((((brfextra LEFT JOIN BrfHarFastighet ON brfextra.Organisationsnr = BrfHarFastighet.Organisationsnr)     
    LEFT JOIN brfkonkurs ON brfextra.Organisationsnr = brfkonkurs.Organisationsnr) 
    LEFT JOIN brfavford ON brfextra.Organisationsnr = brfavford.Organisationsnr) 
    LEFT JOIN brffusion ON brfextra.Organisationsnr = brffusion.Organisationsnr) 
    LEFT JOIN brflikvidation ON brfextra.Organisationsnr = brflikvidation.Organisationsnr) 
    LEFT JOIN brfbolagsverket ON brfextra.Organisationsnr = brfbolagsverket.Organisationsnr  
WHERE 
    (((brfkonkurs.BolagetsStatusKod) IS NULL) 
    AND ((brfavford.BolagetsStatusKod) IS NULL) 
    AND ((brffusion.BolagetsStatusKod) IS NULL) 
    AND ((brflikvidation.BolagetsStatusKod) IS NULL OR (brflikvidation.BolagetsStatusKod) = 34))
```

In the result I need the following additional columns from the log table:

```
BrfId, BrfNamn, Organisationsnr, LogEntry
1,     Billy,   Organisationsnr, You have shown this post before
2,     Carl,    Organisationsnr, NULL
3,     Kent,    Organisationsnr, NULL
4,     Sara,    Organisationsnr, You have shown this post before
```

Please help with code I need to add to my query. I lack coding experience.

Comment: Kindly add few more details like what all those tables that you are joining  holds, and why do you need to join all those tables to get the names of users with their post viewed status?

Comment: All the extra tables contains different company status: bankruptcy, liquidated, fused and deasserted.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this by adding a subselect like the example below. Hope it helps point you in the right direction.

```
SELECT 
    brfbolagsverket.BrfNamn
    , CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foretag_kontaktervisadbrf2017 AS L WHERE L.Organisationsnr = B.Organisationsnr AND L.Foretag_kontaktID = 1247) > 0 THEN 'Lest' ELSE 'Inte lest' END AS NotificationRead
    , brfextra.BrfId
    , brfextra.Organisationsnr
    , brfextra.Gatuadress
    , brfextra.Ort
    , brfextra.Lagenheter
    , brfextra.ByggAr
    , BrfHarFastighet.Fangdatum

FROM (((((
    brfextra AS B
    LEFT JOIN BrfHarFastighet ON brfextra.Organisationsnr = BrfHarFastighet.Organisationsnr) 
    LEFT JOIN brfkonkurs ON brfextra.Organisationsnr = brfkonkurs.Organisationsnr) 
    LEFT JOIN brfavford ON brfextra.Organisationsnr = brfavford.Organisationsnr) 
    LEFT JOIN brffusion ON brfextra.Organisationsnr = brffusion.Organisationsnr) 
    LEFT JOIN brflikvidation ON brfextra.Organisationsnr = brflikvidation.Organisationsnr) 
    LEFT JOIN brfbolagsverket ON brfextra.Organisationsnr = brfbolagsverket.Organisationsnr 

WHERE (((brfkonkurs.BolagetsStatusKod) Is Null) AND ((brfavford.BolagetsStatusKod) Is Null) AND ((brffusion.BolagetsStatusKod) Is Null) AND ((brflikvidation.BolagetsStatusKod) Is Null Or (brflikvidation.BolagetsStatusKod)=34))
```

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry if i post wrong - don't know how to reply properly to Werner Waage answer.

The query is slow when search gets more than 50-70 records - i tried to change to select like

`(SELECT Foretag_kontaktervisadBrfID FROM foretag_kontaktervisadbrf2017 AS L WHERE L.Organisationsnr = B.Organisationsnr AND L.Foretag_kontaktID = '1247') AS NotificationRead`

but its slow to.

My log table **foretag_kontaktervisadbrf2017** have unique posts like this

```
Foretag_kontaktervisadBrfID, Foretag_kontaktID, Organisationsnr, Date001
1,  Billy01,   Acme_01,  2018-01-01
2,  Carl01,    Acme_02,  2018-01-02
3,  Billy01,   Acme_02,  2018-04-15
4,  Carl01,    Acme_03,  2018-14-14
```

Any way to get my previous speed back to the new query?
My original SQL-query worked fast even with results of 1000 records/post.

Comment: If you add a comment to one of my posts i will get notified, also adding an "Answer" to the original post with more followups is also not the standard way of doing it. Stackoverflow is not like a standard forum where you keep asking new questions in the thread when the original question gets answered. To be honest after helping solving a problem its pretty demotivating when you remove the accepted result and continue asking more questions. I could help you with indexes, swapping out the subselect with a join for better performance etc.

Comment: I'm really sorry Werner, i am new here and havent understod how to post right. I'm grateful for your help and knowledge.

Before i do more wrong: 
- should  mark your answer as solved?
- should i delete my post (answer) - if so, do i add this text to my main question in the beginning or at the end of my post?

Comment: Its okay,we are all here to learn :)
Subqueries are usually slow, but there are ways of optimizing your queries. If you have no indexes you should start by adding them on the fields you are joining on. 
After that you can try viewing the execution plan in SQL Management Studio, there you will see what takes the most time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach without using subselects, it assumes that the table **foretag_kontaktervisadbrf2017** contains 0 or 1 row per user.

```
SELECT 
    brfbolagsverket.BrfNamn
    , CASE WHEN L.Foretag_kontaktID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Lest' ELSE 'Inte lest' END AS NotificationRead
    , brfextra.BrfId
    , brfextra.Organisationsnr
    , brfextra.Gatuadress
    , brfextra.Ort
    , brfextra.Lagenheter
    , brfextra.ByggAr
    , BrfHarFastighet.Fangdatum

FROM (((((
    brfextra AS B
    LEFT JOIN BrfHarFastighet ON brfextra.Organisationsnr = BrfHarFastighet.Organisationsnr) 
    LEFT JOIN brfkonkurs ON brfextra.Organisationsnr = brfkonkurs.Organisationsnr) 
    LEFT JOIN brfavford ON brfextra.Organisationsnr = brfavford.Organisationsnr) 
    LEFT JOIN brffusion ON brfextra.Organisationsnr = brffusion.Organisationsnr) 
    LEFT JOIN brflikvidation ON brfextra.Organisationsnr = brflikvidation.Organisationsnr) 
    LEFT JOIN brfbolagsverket ON brfextra.Organisationsnr = brfbolagsverket.Organisationsnr 
    LEFT JOIN foretag_kontaktervisadbrf2017 AS L ON L.Organisationsnr = B.Organisationsnr AND L.Foretag_kontaktID = 1247 -- This id probably needs to come from somewhere else, join in the users etc..

WHERE (((brfkonkurs.BolagetsStatusKod) Is Null) AND ((brfavford.BolagetsStatusKod) Is Null) AND ((brffusion.BolagetsStatusKod) Is Null) AND ((brflikvidation.BolagetsStatusKod) Is Null Or (brflikvidation.BolagetsStatusKod)=34))
```